# PostgreSQL Select into with double precision always returns null when run in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have a function in PL/pgSQL that is trying to back out some data for a date range. The problem I have is that I cannot seem to store the double precision inside a variable. No matter what I do the value is always null when running inside a function. When I run the query from psql command line it returns me the correct data. I can also run the query on another column that is isn't of type double precision and it works fine. For example if I change the column to "total_impressions_for_date_range" it will return me the correct data.

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rollback_date_range_revenue(campaign_id int, 
  begin_date timestamp, end_date timestamp, autocommit boolean)
RETURNS void AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  total_impressions_for_date_range        bigint;
  total_clicks_for_date_range             bigint;
  total_revenue_for_date_range            double precision;
  total_cost_for_date_range               double precision;
BEGIN
  SELECT sum(revenue) INTO total_revenue_for_date_range
  FROM ad_block_summary_hourly
  WHERE ad_run_id IN (
      SELECT ad_run_id FROM ad_run WHERE ad_campaign_id = campaign_id)
    AND ad_summary_time >= begin_date
    AND ad_summary_time < end_date
    AND (revenue IS NOT NULL);

  RAISE NOTICE 'Total revenue for given date range and campaign % was %',
    campaign_id, total_revenue_for_date_range;
```

When I run this I always get a null value for the revenue

```
SELECT rollback_date_range_revenue(8818, '2015-07-20 18:00:00'::timestamp, 
'2015-07-20 20:00:00'::timestamp, false);

NOTICE:  Total revenue for given date range and campaign 8818 was <NULL>
```

When I run it from command line outside of the function it works completely fine

```
    select sum(revenue) from ad_block_summary_hourly where ad_run_id in ( 
select ad_run_id from ad_run where ad_campaign_id = 8818) and ad_summary_time 
>= '2015-07-20 18:00:00'::TIMESTAMP and ad_summary_time < '2015-07-20 
20:00:00'::TIMESTAMP ;

       sum    
    ----------
     3122.533
    (1 row)
```

**EDIT**

Huge thanks to  a_horse_with_no_name and Patrick. This was indeed a problem with a place holder I had called revenue which overlapped with my query. I was thrown off by the fact that the two queries that were not working were both double precision. It just happened to be that those two were also the place holders that I had overlapped with column names.

**2 things to take away from this.**

1. I adopted the p_ naming scheme for place holders suggested by  a_horse_with_no_name, so as to not run into this issue again.
2. Post a full code example, this could have been identified much quicker by the experts.

Comment: Make sure you have no naming conflict between parameters and column names. Give all parameter names a prefix (e.g. `p_campaign_id` instead of `campaign_id`) and re-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, PostgreSQL 8.4 is no longer supported so you should upgrade to 9.4 as soon as you can. Second, your function is obviously abbreviated because some declared variables are not used and there is no `END` clause. These two points together make it somewhat guesswork to give you an answer, but here goes.

Try casting the `double precision` to text, or convert it with `to_char()`. `RAISE NOTICE` expects a string for the expressions to be inserted; possibly in 8.4 this is not automatic.

You could also improve upon your query:

```
...
SELECT sum(sh.revenue) INTO total_revenue_for_date_range
FROM ad_block_summary_hourly sh
JOIN ad_run r USING (ad_run_id)
WHERE r.ad_campaign_id = campaign_id
  AND sh.ad_summary_time BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date;

RAISE NOTICE 'Total revenue for given date range and campaign % was %',
  campaign_id, to_char(total_revenue_for_date_range, '9D999');
...
```

Another potential cause of the problem (guessing again due to lack of information) is a [name collision](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-implementation.html) between a function parameter or variable with a column name from either of the two tables.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, you two were spot on about the name collision.